# Golang strings.EqualFold gives unexpected results

Tags: go, unicode, case-insensitive

In golang (go1.17 windows/amd64) the program below gives the following result:

```
rune1 = U+0130 'İ'
rune2 = U+0131 'ı'
lower(rune1) = U+0069 'i'
upper(rune2) = U+0049 'I'
strings.EqualFold(İ, ı) = false
strings.EqualFold(i, I) = true
```

I thought that `strings.EqualFold` would check strings for equality under Unicode case folding; however, the above example seem to give a counter-example. Clearly both runes can be folded (by hand) into code points that are equal under case folding.

**Question**: is golang correct that `strings.EqualFold(İ, ı)` is `false`? I expected it to yield `true`. And if golang is correct, why would that be? Or is this behaviour according to some Unicode specification.

What am I missing here.

---

Program:

```
func TestRune2(t *testing.T) {
   r1 := rune(0x0130) // U+0130 'İ'
   r2 := rune(0x0131) // U+0131 'ı'
   r1u := unicode.ToLower(r1)
   r2u := unicode.ToUpper(r2)

   t.Logf("\nrune1 = %#U\nrune2 = %#U\nlower(rune1) = %#U\nupper(rune2) = %#U\nstrings.EqualFold(%s, %s) = %v\nstrings.EqualFold(%s, %s) = %v",
      r1, r2, r1u, r2u, string(r1), string(r2), strings.EqualFold(string(r1), string(r2)), string(r1u), string(r2u), strings.EqualFold(string(r1u), string(r2u)))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is "correct" behaviour. These letters do not behave normal under case folding. See:
http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/CaseFolding.txt

U+0131 has full case folding "F" and special "T":

```
T: special case for uppercase I and dotted uppercase I
   - For non-Turkic languages, this mapping is normally not used.
   - For Turkic languages (tr, az), this mapping can be used instead
     of the normal mapping for these characters.
     Note that the Turkic mappings do not maintain canonical equivalence
     without additional processing.
     See the discussions of case mapping in the Unicode Standard for more information.
```

I think there is no way of to force package strings to use the tr or az mapping.

Answer (score 2):

From the [strings.EqualFold](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.2:src/strings/strings.go;l=970) source - `unicode.ToLower` and `unicode.ToUpper` are not used.

Instead, it uses [unicode.SimpleFold](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode#SimpleFold) to see if a particular rune is "foldable" and therefore potentially comparable:

```
// General case. SimpleFold(x) returns the next equivalent rune > x
// or wraps around to smaller values.
r := unicode.SimpleFold(sr)
for r != sr && r < tr {
    r = unicode.SimpleFold(r)
}
```

The rune `İ` is not foldable. It's lowercase code-point is:

```
r := rune(0x0130)        // U+0130 'İ'
lr := unicode.ToLower(r) // U+0069 'i'

fmt.Printf("foldable? %v\n", r != unicode.SimpleFold(r))   // foldable? false
fmt.Printf("foldable? %v\n", lr != unicode.SimpleFold(lr)) // foldable? true
```

If a rune is not foldable (i.e. `SimpleFold` returns itself) - then that rune can only match itself and no other code-point.

https://play.golang.org/p/105x0I714nS